# UIWindow makeKeyWindow: versus makeKeyAndVisible:

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, xamarin.ios, uikit

My app is using a 2nd UIWindow to show a special screen if iOS wants to take a screenshot of the app.
By accident I used `[UIWindow makeKeyWindow:]` on my main window if I wanted to remove the 2nd window again. This really should be `makeKeyAndVisible:` instead but I'm wondering why it worked at all.
I mean: most of the time (99%), my 2nd window was removed as expected and my main window became visible.
I'm asking because I'm wondering if I have really found the problem or if there might still be something else?

Or could it be that the method was incorrectly bound in (previous) MonoTouch versions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each method maps to the selector of the same name [`makeKeyAndVisible`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIWindow_Class/UIWindowClassReference/UIWindowClassReference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIWindow/makeKeyAndVisible) and [`makeKeyWindow`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIWindow_Class/UIWindowClassReference/UIWindowClassReference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIWindow/makeKeyWindow).

> Or could it be that the method was incorrectly bound in (previous) MonoTouch versions?

GIT history shows (me ;-) that both never changed since they were first added (more than two years ago).

Documentation about the former states:

> You can also hide and reveal a window using the inherited hidden property of `UIView`.

Maybe this happens in your code (or even within the iOS code).

Comment: I'm never changing the hidden property. That's why I'm wondering that it is working at all.

Comment: @Krumelur : a quick test using `MakeKeyWindow` (instead of `MakeKeyAndVisible`) shows me a black screen (iOS 5.1). My only guess is that something, inside your code indirectly triggered the visibility of your `UIWindow`. All I can say for **sure** is that this did not change in MonoTouch...

Comment: Add this finish off the Visible part of makeKeyAndVisible:    self.window.hidden = NO;